# How to I set a timeout for an specific action in Coded UI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Does someone know how can I set a timeout for a test in coded UI? I know that you can do `Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = x` but my test is finding the control, what happens is that it can not access the control (because of a bug of the UI, but I can not change the UI because is not my project). The test is looping trying to click the control and never fails, I have to manually cancel the test.

I need that my test keep running after it fails the click . . .  this is because if I move the mouse out the control after I clicked, the UI keep work. So I need to click the control (failing the click), then move the mouse and click again (that's the way to workaround the bug).

So

-How do I set a timeout for an specific action in the playback?
something like

```
Playback.PlaySettings.ActionTimeOut = 1000;
Mouse.Click(control, new Point (3,3));
Playback.PlaySettings.ResetToDefault;
```

Thanks

Comment: A ".testsettings" file can be used to specify a timeout for individual tests and/or for the whole test run. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175.aspx

Comment: Thanks but I can not do that, I need the test to keep going I just need that the test stop trying to click over the control, one attempt will work for my case.

Comment: Can you expand on "can not access the control"? There are a variety of properties of the control that check whether it is visible or enabled or hidden, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. It should throw an exception in these cases. I think CUIT doesn't have a feature to set action timeout or it's hidden in one of its "less easily accessible" classes. Working out this feature seems like too big a hassle to me.

I suggest implementing the workaround you use: click the button and don't care about the results. So just find the button, set the focus on it or its top level window, get its bounding rectangle, a clickable point and do a mouse click on that point (then move the mouse again if it's necessary). Something like:

```
control.TopParent.SetFocus();
var point = control.GetClickablePoint();
var br = control.BoundingRectangle;
var pointToClick = new Point(br.X + point.X, br.Y + point.Y);
Mouse.Click(pointToClick);
```

If `GetClickablePoint` fails then try

```
var pointToClick = new Point(br.X + br.Width / 2, br.Y + br.Height / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the test going after it fails you can use:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;
```

and have the mouse click twice.

Another work around could be having the mouse click on the button, click in the white space next to it, then click on the button again.

If the bug has any relation to a thread still processing, you could also use prior to the click:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the control enabled or exist etc. if false -> use Assert.Fail(message),if true -> click on the button with Mouse.Click(new Point(x,y)).